# How to execute code periodically until first successful execution using Rx?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I want to execute some code in repetitive manner:

- Code should be executed until first successful call (not throws an exception) or calls count not reached some N;
- Each next call (after failed one) should be performed after some delay T;
- Result of each execution should be handled by subscription (including exceptions);
- Execution can be cancelled somehow (using CancellationToken for example).

*Actually I have plans to use that code to perform calls to some server that can be down for couple of seconds sometimes.*

*I am new with Rx and tried some approaches before ask that question (kill about 2 hours for reading docs and writing code) and decided, that I need some example.*

I want to get something like this (not working code, just prototype):

```
Observalbe.Create(
    () => {
        // TODO: some code here (it can throw exceptions)...
    }
).Retry(N)
.Delay(T)
.Subscribe(
    result => { Log.Info("The result is {0}", result); },
    error => { Log.Error(error, "Error occured"); }
)
```

I know, that Rx is magic, but what kind of that magic should I use to achieve desired result?

Comment: This sounds a little bit like an XY problem. Can you please explain what is the underlying need you have for your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be better off using something like [Polly](https://github.com/michael-wolfenden/Polly), it allows you to specify exception handling policies succinctly.

```
var policy = Policy.Handle<Exception>()
// Retry 5 times waiting 1 second in between
                .WaitAndRetry(5, x => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), (e,d,c) =>
                {                   
                    Console.WriteLine("Count = {0}, Message = {1}", c.Count, e.Message);
                }); 

policy.Execute(() => 
{
   throw new Exception("Error!");
});
```

Comment: I'd never heard of Polly before but it looks fantastic! Definitely something to have in mind for future use.

Comment: Hell, it is exactly what I need :-) Thank you.